# in bamboo : Is there any way to download a shared artifact event if the shared artifact generating plan failed?

Tags: bamboo, bamboo-artifacts

I want to download a shared artifact using artifact download plugin. But it seems the plugin only download the latest successful build's artifact. But my requirement is to download the artifact even the generator plan fails. I don't want to use Bamboo credentials in a separate script to download it using a URL. Is there any way that I can download the failed plan's artifact?